# go-staticcheck: value of file is never used (SA4006)

Tags: go

I wrote a function for logging errors, it works, but the IDE writes about an error(this value of file is never used (SA4006) go-staticcheck)

Sample Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func errorLoger(err error, msg string) {
    fileWrite, _ := os.OpenFile("erroBot.log", os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    log.SetOutput(fileWrite)
    log.Fatalf("%s:%s", err, msg)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("file Open")
    file, err := os.OpenFile("no-file.txt", os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    errorLoger(err, "Error Open File")
    defer file.Close()
}
```

Please clarify what is wrong and where I made a mistake.

Comment: The staticcheck output will show you the exact location in the source with the problem. I assume it's referring to the `file` that you never read or write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's now how it's done. Log errors only if there's an error i.e., currently even if there's no error, you're exiting out with log.Fatal and writing to erroBot.log.

Here's a better (and correct) to do the same:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
)

func SetupErrLogger(file string) {
    f, err := os.OpenFile(file, os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Logger setup failed:", err)
    }
    log.SetOutput(f)
}

func main() {
    SetupErrLogger("erroBot.log")

    file, err := os.OpenFile("no-file.txt", os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()
    // Do something with file, else SA4006 is raised
}
```

Comment: I still don't think this is correct. At no point are you closing the "erroBot.log" file. Maybe add a `if c, ok := log.Writer().(io.WriteCloser); ok { c.Close() }` at the end.

Comment: I said it's a better version. @Gavin what you have suggested is right but it won't still work when there's an error. For eg. log.Fatalln is called and it exits from there only with `os.Exit(1)` so defer won't even work. We need to structure the program differently to achieve that but for the sake of simplicity (targeted towards solving the problem of OP specifically) I avoided all that.

Comment: @Shurilla Note that when you are writing to a file; it's also recommended to close it. So think of ways how you can close the file when you're exiting from your program. There are many ways, but find the one that fits the best with your program.

Comment: Maybe I misread the "and correct" statement in your answer... Anyway, I didn't mention `defer` in my comment, and you could just as easily log the error and return instead of using `os.Exit` or any method that would call it e.g. `log.Fatal`.

Comment: Thank you for your help , with your help I figured out this task